# I can't get my abbreviations list to print using Overleaf

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, acronyms, thesis

I'm writing my PhD thesis using LaTeX, and whatever I try I can't seem to get my abbreviations list to print. I'm using the report document class. At the moment I have in my main document preamble:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\loadglsentries[acronym]{abbreviations}
```

In a separate file in the same folder (called 'abbreviations') I have my abbreviations listed in the following format:

```
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{rt}{RT}{reverse transcription}
```

Where I want to print the abbreviations list, I have the following:

```
\chapter*{Abbreviations}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
```

The abbreviations are being generated within my thesis text in the right way, and I'm not getting an error message. I've searched this forum, read the wikibook and read the Overleaf guide to the glossaries package, and nothing has helped. Ideally I would like the abbreviations list to be printed before the main body of my thesis, but I've also tried putting it in at the end and that doesn't work either. I've tried adding `\makeglossaries`, `\makeacronyms`, `\setglossarystyle{list}`, `\input{abbreviations}` in just about every configuration possible as well as many other things, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple example.

`abbreviations.tex` has a single line

`\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{rt}{RT}{reverse transcription}`

You need to use `\makeglossaries` and use the acronym in the text.

Then `pdflatex` + `makeglossaries` + `pdflatex`.

[image: a]

The chapter **Acronyms**s will appear after **Abbreviations**

To print all acronyms defined use `\glsaddallunused` after `\printglossary`.

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex 

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries % needed <<<<<

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\loadglsentries[acronym]{abbreviations}

\begin{document}
    
For example \acrlong{rt}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{rt}. % needed <<<<<
    
    \chapter*{Abbreviations}

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    
    %\glsaddallunused % prints all acronyms defined
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Frustratingly, this works perfectly when I copy this in a test folder, but not when I do the exact same thing in my thesis project file. I've tried copying all of the preamble from my thesis project into the test folder and it still works, so I guess it's not another package that's stopping it from working. To be honest at this stage I think I'd be better cutting my losses and just typing it all out, unless anyone can think of another reason why the exact same code would be working in one file and not another?

Comment: @Eva Try commenting out the content of your thesis, part by part, until you find where the problem originates. IMPORTANT: Each time **delete all the files** generated by the previous run: toc, glc, aux, etc.